# Understanding ripple in oscilloscope

Tags: power-supply, oscilloscope, ripple

I have a linear (non-switched) power supply that states in the specs a ripple of 10 mV p-p

Measuring it with the oscilloscope, as you can see in the image it measures Vpp = 30mV.

The oscilloscope is measuring 30 mV on those strong, high spikes, but what is the actual power supply ripple, those high spikes, or the thick line that is about 10 mV?

What can be those high peaks that are seen in the image? Maybe some interference generated by some c.i. regulator?

[image]

I have connected the oscilloscope probe to the source crocodiles

[image]

Power Supply Specifications

[image]

Comment: You should describe your test method clearly, preferably with a circuit diagram

Comment: I'll try, but it's just connecting the oscilloscope probe to the output pins of the power supply, no components involved

Comment: Please link to the datasheet for said power supply and include a photo of your measurement setup.

Comment: What is scope bandwidth set as? What is your probing setup? (Note mere connections don't matter: wire position, length, etc. all matter at these frequencies!)

Comment: Linear regulator will not have ripple like those spikes. There must either be a switch mode supply before it, or nearby it. Also commonly the noise is measured with 20 MHz band limit, which the scope settings shows to be off.

Comment: As for what the noise is, the two most likely culprits would either be line noise (50Hz etc + harmonics) or the switch regulator frequency (+ harmonics). The latter seems more likely here.

Comment: linear regulator do not have ripple in general, unless you load them with a switched periodic load.

Comment: I have added new images and font specifications

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said by @Tim Williams and @Justme, be careful when making oscilloscope measurements with low resolution. In some cases, voltage peaks don't exist, they're artifacts.

Here's a naive measurement (yellow probe):

[image]

The same measurement with a ground spring tip (green probe). The green probe is above the yellow probe:

[image]

[image]

And the result. The voltage peaks don't exist, they're artifacts. Artifacts arise from mutual inductance coupling between the probe loop, formed by the probe and its ground, and the environment.

[image]

Make sure you measure with a ground spring tip and in AC coupling.

Comment: This is good advice and the likely explanation for the "background noise" in the picture, but I don't think it explains the spikes.

Comment: Thanks... right now I'm without the oscilloscope but when I get it back here I'll try your advice