Increased noise at Transformer Secondary with no input signal
created this prototype (on a PCB):

Input signal (V3) frequency range is 0-4.5kHz, 0-20Vpp.
With no input signal connected (no V3), I see this noise at OUT-A:

Worse, noise increase at 1:1 transformer secondary (LOAD):

What's going on here? Should I put a low pass filter at load side?
edit:
added +70VDC rail scope shot (blue), OUT-A (yellow):


What is your probe technique?  How much ripple is on your power supply?  Is the noise synchronous with the power supply ripple?

picture added above

@ArielNarboada, An incorrect measurement may reveal noise that does not exist on OUT-A, which may be picked up by the probe. Do you have a ground plan? Do you use a ground spring tip ? See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/677017/274961


The power rail has about 0.2Vp-p of ripple. That's too much. It should be clean.

The op-amp may not be stable, but it's hard to tell with supply ripple present. You want to get the op-amp over-damped first, and only then start to make things faster again when stability is dubious.
Add a series resistor - start with 50Ω - between the op-amp and the transformer. And increase C3 to 100pF. You can reduce these values once everything works.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
